# refreshing data from a plist

Tags: ios, xcode, loops, plist, ibaction

I am trying to create a loop from a plist depending on the amount of items in the array here is my plist code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>question</key>
    <string>2 + 2 = ?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>Ans</key>
    <string>B</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>question</key>
    <string>2 + 4 = ?</string>
    <key>A</key>
    <string>3</string>
    <key>B</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>C</key>
    <string>9</string>
    <key>Ans</key>
    <string>B</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

So there are two items in my array. I want the screen to load the first item and display it and then using a button in the interface display the screen again with the second list of items

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
rootArray = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"question" ofType:@"plist"]];
currentQuestion = -1;
[self showNextQuestion];
}
-(void) showNextQuestion{
    currentQuestion++;
    int numItems = [rootArray count];
    NSMutableArray *question = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *A = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *B = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *C = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];
    NSMutableArray *CorrectAns = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numItems];

for (NSDictionary *itemData in rootArray) {
    [question addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"question"]];
    [A addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"A"]];
    [B addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"B"]];
    [C addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"C"]];
    [CorrectAns addObject:[itemData objectForKey:@"Ans"]];
    self.questionasked.text =question[currentQuestion];
    self.answer1.text = A[currentQuestion];
    self.answer2.text = B[currentQuestion];
    self.answer3.text = C[currentQuestion];

    }
}
```

I know i have to create some sort of a loop and use an action but I am not sure how

Answer (score 1):

You've already got everything in rootArray, so you don't need to do all that stuff with the NSMutableArrays.  Just do something like

```
NSDictionary *item = rootArray[currentQuestion];
self.questionasked.text = item[@"question"];
self.answer1.text = item[@"A"];
```

And set up a UIButton that calls [self showNextQuestion]; when you tap it.